# ASP.Net Authorization Issue for ASPNet in Windows Integrated Site

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a webpage that emits files (images) (through Response.TransmitFile) that is working ok.

However, when I publish the site to IIS (5.1), it starts randomly to emit 401 and 403 status codes instead of the expected files(images)

The IIS site is supposed to have Windows Integrated Authentication without allowing anonymous users, however, I configured the locations on my web.config to allow users to get the files

```
  <location path="ViewFile.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

I have set permissions for The users \IUSR_, \ASPNET, My own domain user, and even for everyone, but i don't get to solve the problem.

Any suggestions at how can I handle the problem?

**Edit 1:**

When I activate anonymous authentication in IIS, the site works fine, but then the domain authentication doesn't appear. I understand that the anonymous authentication prevails over anyother authentication

Answer (score 0):

**Some points to get you started:**

- What do you see in the Windows Event
  log?
- If you take out the authorization
  configuration, does it work OK -- or
  do you still get 401 and 403 codes?
- You mentioned that it happens
  'randomly' -- is it connected with
  certain users?  Or times of heavier
  load?  Or certain files?
- TransmitFile doesn't buffer in memory
  -- are these large files?

Update 6/29/2011 5:02pm - You didn't mention you were publishing locally before.  Have you tried [this configuration hack](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861/en-us)?  I have had to use it when using Windows Authentication and IIS locally.

Comment: i'm the only user, i'm doing this in my dev machine, these are 3kb 4kb png's and jpg's

Comment: Updated answer to include a link to the MSDN IIS Windows authentication configuration hack (useful when running IIS locally)

Comment: well... in fact i'm getting the error both locally and in server... it's like the browser makes requests to the server before the authentication credentials arrive